# dojo.position on floating divs

Tags: html, dojo, position, floating

somehow does dojo.position not return the correct left and top values if used on a floating div. 
There is always an offset if the node is followed by an other floating div.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I created JSFiddle to help understand your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/cLX9E/. It seems to working as it should be. Provide more details.

Comment: you'll need to specify your browser, Dojo version etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the JSFiddle link, nice tool, didn't know that.

I found the problem:
The floating divs were surrounded by a link and the onClick trigger was in the a-tag.
So dojo.position fetched the position from the a-tag, which doesn't float properly as you can see here:

(I had to put the function in the HTML-box, because in the JS-box I got the error: "unknown function: showPos"!?)
http://jsfiddle.net/cLX9E/23/

-> Mozilla Firefox 4.0
-> Dojo 1.6